# How to use selenium to run indicated versions of multi browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I now review the capabilities of selenium to do auto testing work.
I knew selenium can support parallel multi browsers testing by webdrivers. However, how can I specify the versions of browsers to test, such as ie8,ie9 , firefox27...?
Is it possible to do this in selenium?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not, the alternative would be to use multiple machines each with a different version of the browser.

Machine 1 - IE8.

Machine 2 - IE9.

Machine 3 - IE10.

And you can use the selenium server to test IE across all 3 machines in parallel. 
See link below on how to use the selenium grid:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You'd need to use a multithreading function in your script. Here's my example in Python.

Start thread 1 with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie("path to IE8")
#do stuff
```

Start thread 2 with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie("path to IE9")
#do stuff
```

Implement multi-threading with this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm